# How to insert looping with existing id in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I want to implement insert into the database with looping in Laravel. inside looping, I want to get the latest ID of the **Room** table, which will be used for the next insert. here is my code

```
foreach ($listDataRoom as $key => $res) {
    $res['hotel_id'] = $resultHotel->id;
    
    $latestRecordRoom = Room::latest()->first();
    if ($latestRecordRoom !== null) {
        $latestIdRoom = $latestRecordRoom->getAttributes();
        $idRoom = $latestIdRoom['id'] + 1;
    } else {
        $idRoom = 31;
    }

    $res['id'] = $idRoom;
    $roomModel = new Room();
    $roomModel->fill($res);
    
    $resultRoomServices = Room::create($roomModel->getAttributes());
}
```

**Update**
here I included my migrations schema on Room Table

```
Schema::create('rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('hotel_id')->unsigned()  ;
            $table->foreign('hotel_id')->references('id')->on('hotels')->onDelete('cascade');
                       
            $table->string('room_name', 100);
            $table->integer('show_order');
            
            $table->string('room_status');
            
            $table->integer('room_allowance')->nullable();;
            
            $table->integer('room_availability')->nullable();;
            
            $table->text('description');
            $table->decimal('discount', 5, 2);
            $table->text('image_gallery')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This works sometimes, but when I have 3 or more data, this looping gets an error in MySQL "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry". I assume the insert process is not completed inside the loop. How is the best way to insert the last id inside a looping

Comment: Is the `id` of the table non-incremental? Why is there a constant id `$idRoom = 31;` declared? Will there be only 31 results, what's the case?

Comment: yes its not auto increment, the constant id $idRoom will be use as starting number of primary Id

Comment: Can you share your db structure and the entire error?

Comment: @Adi I updated my question with migrations schema

Comment: after some search i decide to use sleep(n time). Yes its not best practice but i have to make it work.